# Outlook Quick Search Folder Structure by Name

Tags: vba, outlook, office365, ms-office, outlook-addin

Is there any easy way to quickly search for the name of a folder in Outlook's inbox folder structure?

I am talking about this:

[image]

I have to categorize emails into this folder structure as they arrive but 99% of the time is looking for the right folder...

We are running our own Exchange and I am using Outlook over rdp

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZDKS.png

Comment: [Find a Folder Misplaced in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296811/find-a-folder-misplaced-in-outlook)

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property of method for that.

You need to develop a VBA macro or add-in to ge the job done. For example, you can iterate over the folders structure to find the required one. The [Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864011(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Folder class returns the Folders collection that represents all the folders contained in the specified Folder. So, you may walk down to the tree recursively.